# display and edit value into geometrynode properties

Tags: modeling, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

[image]

how to display and edit this value of a node in the GEOMETRYNODE property window

thanks

---

In fact the value I want to make available in the property panel is a scale value of the "value" node. I'll try another way. thank you very much.

Comment: I see @Chris and I both worked on an answer. But just to clarify, we both supposed you wanted the value as input to use it in _GN_, correct? Because the red arrow comes from the _Output Attributes_

Comment: The usual workflow is that you set a value in the modifier, and connect it from the Group Input to the place of choice, as in Chris' and Gordon's answers. The opposite is not easy to accomplish - could be done using a Python script, but I wouldn't recommend even trying, as I don't see a good reason to do it in such a way.

Answer (score 4):

use combine xyz and plug it into the group input node like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution: drag a connection from the *Translation* input to an empty socket on the *Group Input* node, then you can edit all three values.

If you only want the Z value, plug a *Combine XYZ* node into the *Translation* and drag a connection of the Z input to an empty socket of the *Group Input*.

[image: translation to input]

[image: z value to input]